# How to add the current iteration's value to the previous iteration's value in a loop C#

Tags: c#

I can find a Java version for my question, but not C#. My current attempt goes crazy when attempting to add them. I feel like there is a simple fix, but I'm struggling to think of it.

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
int[] input = { 28, 2, 3, -3, -2, 1, 2, 35, -1, 0, 0, -1 };
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    int x = input[i];
    int y = input[i++];
    int output = x + y;
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice per iteration.

Comment: `i++` changes the value of `i`. `i+1` just gets the next value - but don't let that get to `input.Length` or you will get an IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task answer is (updated):

```
var sum = 0;
var input = new int[] { 28, 2, 3, -3, -2, 1, 2, 35, -1, 0, 0, -1 };
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
{
    sum += input[i];
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I explained it badly. I'm looking to add the new number that is produced to the previous number. So 28,2,3,-3 would become 28,30,33,30 for instance.

Comment: @Ben   var sum = 0;
            var input = new int[] { 28, 2, 3, -3, -2, 1, 2, 35, -1, 0, 0, -1 };
            for (var i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                sum += input[i];
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code :

```
int[] input = { 28, 2, 3, -3, -2, 1, 2, 35, -1, 0, 0, -1 };
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
{
    int x = input[i];
    int y = input[i + 1];
    int output = x + y;
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```